# How to replace the dataset column names according to the col name table?

Tags: r

I have a datasets like this:

```
my_data <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = letters[1:5], x33_1 = c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 5))
```

Now the col's names are x1, x2...x33_1...

I also have a table which contains both x series name and their corresponding real name, like this:

```
variable. variable2
x1         record_id
x2         event name
x33_1      mud
```

My question is how to automatically replace all column names based on table information? I have 123 variables from x1 to x123,  I also have the tale like above which records their corresponding real names, is there possible that there is kind of function i do not need to input them one by one?

Thanks~~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `rename` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

rename(my_data, deframe(rev(df1)))
  record_id event_name mud
1         1          a  NA
2         2          b   2
3         3          c   3
4         4          d  NA
5         5          e   5
```

---

df1 is as shown below:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = '  variable  variable2
    1       x1  record_id
    2       x2 event_name
    3    x33_1        mud', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks! May I ask whether the order of each name must be same in both datasets? The code works for my example, but not for my real data, I can only see the difference is that the example above has the same order for each var's name while my real datasets col name like x1, x2, x32, x34....x123,x33_1, x33_2. and in table, the order is like x1, x2, x32, x33_1, x33_2, x34, ...x123. Thx~~

Comment: @Rstudyer the order doesn't matter

Comment: thx~~~I know which part is wrong for my script, thanks for your great help~~!